# Cloud function with python multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions

how do i run the following in google cloud function?

I want to run some code in parallel because cloud function only has 540 seconds to finish an operation

I'm wondering specifically about how to call the main

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

full code

```
import concurrent.futures
import math

PRIMES = [
    112272535095293,
    112582705942171,
    112272535095293,
    115280095190773,
    115797848077099,
    1099726899285419]

def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    sqrt_n = int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)))
    for i in range(3, sqrt_n + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for number, prime in zip(PRIMES, executor.map(is_prime, PRIMES)):
            print('%d is prime: %s' % (number, prime))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I've not tried this but I don't see why it wouldn't work. Can you not just replace `def main()` with e.g. `def my_func(request)` (`request` for consistency on the signature) and then reference `my_func` as the function to execute when you deploy? Revise references to `main` elsewhere.

Comment: I tried that and it works.

Comment: I think your challenge will be in determining how many primes you can calculate before the 540s timeout. With larger numbers, you may hit the timeout before `is_prime` returns even for a single value.

Comment: after solving the ```__main```, i see a bigger issue, multiprocessing is not supported in google cloud functions and ProcessPoolExecutor() will not work

Comment: Interesting. It's not that `concurrent` isn't supported, but that you only get one process. I revised the source to `os.getpid()` within `is_prime` and only one concurrent process is supported.

Comment: thanks for confirming!!! google is cheating here with only allowing a single process per cloud function :(